# How to hide Jtable in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I hide the table using`accountTable.setVisible(false);` but now it it not showing whenver `accountTable.setVisible(true);`is called. please tell me  how to solve it or give an alternative option for hiding Jtable.The jtable is in a jpanel already

Comment: Do you need to show the JPanel as well?

Comment: yes i want to show jpanel

Answer (score 0):

try calling the jpanel (where the jTable is on) revalidate() and repaint() functions after setting the table visible

Answer (score 0):

> an alternative option for hiding Jtable.

A JTable is typically displayed in a JScrollPane. So one approach would be:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( null ); // to hide the table
```

and then:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( table ); // to show the table.
```

This assumes that you have space on the panel to actually show the table. If there is no space on the panel to reshow the table then you may need to pack() the frame as well.